# Concurrent Object Pool giving a boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, tbb

I wanted to implement a concurrent object pool where in a shared_ptr is returned and explicitly returning it to the pool is not required. I basically allocated an array pushed shared_ptrs for it in a concurrent queue and implemented a custom deletor. Seems to work. Am I missing anything?

```
#ifndef CONCURRENTOBJECTPOOL_H
#define CONCURRENTOBJECTPOOL_H

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_array.hpp>
#include <tbb/concurrent_queue.h>

namespace COP
{

template<typename T>
class ConcurrentObjectPool;

namespace 
{
template<typename T>
class ConcurrentObjectPoolDeletor
{
public:
  ConcurrentObjectPoolDeletor(ConcurrentObjectPool<T>& aConcurrentObjectPool): 
  _concurrentObjectPool(aConcurrentObjectPool) {}

  void operator()(T *p) const;

private:
  ConcurrentObjectPool<T>& _concurrentObjectPool;  
};
} // Anonymous namespace for ConcurrentObjectPoolDeletor

template <typename T>
class ConcurrentObjectPool
{
 public:
 ConcurrentObjectPool(const unsigned int aPoolSize)
   : _goingDown(false),
     _poolSize(aPoolSize), 
     _pool(new T[_poolSize]),
     _ConcurrentObjectPoolDeletor(*this)
  {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _poolSize; ++i)
      {
        boost::shared_ptr<T> curr(&_pool[i], _ConcurrentObjectPoolDeletor);
        _objectQueue.push(curr);
      }
  }

  boost::shared_ptr<T> loan()
  {
    boost::shared_ptr<T> curr;
    _objectQueue.pop(curr);
    return curr;
  }

  ~ConcurrentObjectPool()
  {
    _goingDown = true;
    _objectQueue.clear();
  }

 private:
  void payBack(T * p)
  {
    if (! _goingDown)
      {
        boost::shared_ptr<T> curr(p, _ConcurrentObjectPoolDeletor);
        _objectQueue.push(curr);
      }
  }

  bool _goingDown;
  const unsigned int _poolSize; 
  const boost::shared_array<T> _pool;
  const ConcurrentObjectPoolDeletor<T> _ConcurrentObjectPoolDeletor;
  tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue<boost::shared_ptr<T> > _objectQueue;
  friend class ConcurrentObjectPoolDeletor<T>;
};

namespace
{
template<typename T>
void ConcurrentObjectPoolDeletor<T>::operator()(T *p) const
{
  _concurrentObjectPool.payBack(p);
}
} // Anonymous namespace for ConcurrentObjectPoolDeletor

} // Namespace COP

#endif // CONCURRENTOBJECTPOOL_H
```

Comment: This belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Anonymous namespace in a header seems like a bad idea to me; a quick way to an ODR violation.

Comment: Does [Boost.Flyweight](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/flyweight/doc/index.html) already solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a race between setting the `_goingDown` flag in the destructor of `ConcurrentObjectPool` and reading the flag in `payBack()`. It can lead to memory leaks.

Actually, maybe it's better if you do not try to make the destructor safe to run concurrently with `payBack()`. It's not safe anyway, starting from the fact that the `_goingDown` flag is a part of the pool object and so accessing it after the pool is destroyed would cause undefined behavior - i.e. all objects must be returned to the pool before it is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good.  Are you experiencing any problems using it?

Comment: Need to be sure. I always screw up with concurrency.